# log in user python, how validate a log in user?

Tags: python, django, authentication

i can't log in with a user, i am not sure why, i can log with a admin accout but, i create a model to new user and i can't log with it.

**model.py**

```
class MiUsuario(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name='Dirección de e-mail',
            max_length=255,
            unique=True,
        )
    nombre_completo = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre Completo del usuario(a)",max_length=150, unique= True, null=True)
    nombre_de_usuario = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre de Usuario",max_length=15, unique= True)
    Numero_de_identificacion = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Número de identificación",null=True)
    Pagina_web = models.URLField(verbose_name="Página Web",blank=True)
    Celular = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Número de celular",null=True)
    Telefono = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Número de télefono",null=True)
    Ext = models.PositiveIntegerField("Extension del télefono",null=True)
    Nombre_Empresa = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre de la empresa",max_length=50,null=True)
    Cargo_Contacto = models.CharField(verbose_name="Cargo del cliente",max_length=50,null=True)
    GeneroEscoger = ((1,"Sin especificar"),(2,'Masculino'),(3,'Femenino'))
    Genero = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Genero',choices=GeneroEscoger, default=1)
    Ciudades = ( (1,'Bogotá'),(2,'Medellin'),(3,'Cali'),(4,'Barranquilla'),(5,'Cartagena'),(6,'Cucuta'),(7,'Ibagué'),(8,'Bucaramanga'),(9,'Otro'))
    Ciudad = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Ciudad',choices=Ciudades, default=1,)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = AdministracionUsuarios()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'nombre_de_usuario'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['Numero_de_identificacion','Nombre_Empresa','Telefono']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.nombre_completo
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.nombre_de_usuario
    def _str_(self):
        return self.nombre_de_usuario
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

then i use a form to valid if user exist in MiUsuario

**form.py**

```
class LoginUserForm(forms.Form):
    """Authentication form which uses boostrap CSS."""
    usuario = MiUsuario()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254,widget=forms.TextInput({'placeholder': 'Nombre de usuario'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),widget=forms.PasswordInput({'placeholder':'Contraseña'}))
    def usuario():
        if  usuario.objects.filter(nombre_de_usuario!=username) and  usuario.objects.filter(password!=password):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrecta')
```

after call the form in layout.html, but when i try log in, just relog the page and no sign with a user account, but if i try with a admin accout, relog without troubles
**url.py**

```
url(r'^login$', 'app.views.index', name='Vulpini.co'),
```

how can i do this log Works
**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, Estado=False)
    formlog = LoginUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            username = cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = cleaned_data.get('password')
            email = cleaned_data.get('email')
            user_model = MiUsuario.objects.crear_usuario(nombre_de_usuario=username,email=email, password=password)
            user_model.save()
        else:
            form = RegistroUserForm()
    else: 
        form = RegistroUserForm()
    context = {
        'formlog' : formlog,
        'form': form,
        'notifi': notifi,
    }

    return render(request,'app/index.html',context)
```

the view from i get the form

Comment: Please be more explicit about which framework you're using. I know it's django only because its one of your question's tags.

Comment: @pedromanoel django 1.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py with your custom user model like:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.MiUsuario'
```

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure. It changes the tables that are available, and it will affect the construction of foreign keys and many-to-many relationships. If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.
>
> Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported
>   by makemigrations and will result in you having to manually fix your
>   schema, port your data from the old user table, and possibly manually
>   reapply some migrations.

check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) for more details

Comment: @alfredohb.q Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported by makemigrations. So I would recommend you to first delete all your tables and delete all migration files for all apps in their respective migration folder, then set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.MiUsuario'` in your settings.py file. Next do `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `migrate`.

Comment: @alfredohb.q just to clarify, I wrote delete all your tables, what I meant was to DROP all your tables and in all your tables if there are any foreign key/manytomany etc. references to user then replace it with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. 
Example: Instead of `owner = models.ForeignKey(User)`  do `owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`